# How to concatenate a variable in a VBA formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I insert a variable in the place of 86?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Temp1!R2C1:R86C2,2,FALSE),0)"
```

eg: if variable name is *TotalRow*

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Temp1!R2C1:R&TotalRow&C2,2,FALSE),0)"
```

The variable name is coming instead of its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Temp1!R2C1:R" & TotalRow & "C2,2,FALSE),0)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, simply saying the spacing of text and & is important

Comment: No problem! The syntax does take a while to catch on to.